# Remove OutputCache with multiple VaryByParam

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have a action like this:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByParam = "page;categor;searchString")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? category, int page = 1, string searchString = null)
```

This action can have multiple cache result. its fine so far. but when i post a new content, i like to remove all those multiple cache result.

I know i can use `RemoveOutputCacheItem` with a list of urls in a foreach or so..

```
var urls = new List<string>();
foreach (var url in urls)
{
   HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
}
```

But for that i have to make several connection to my database and get categories, pages and even if somehow i get all the search string, it's still cause too much trouble.

My question is, Is there a better way to remove all those cache at once?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to remove all those cache at once

Not that I know off. But You can remove cached item for a specific controller action method like below (assuming that your controller name is `controller1`). Idea taken from [Clearing the ASP.Net MVC Cache](https://dzone.com/articles/programmatically-clearing-0)

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action("Index", "controller1", new { category = 1234  }));
```

Comment: Yes have seen that but per my knowledge, there is no such way; yes once duration trips off it will cleared.